# Is null char appended twice at the end of string

Tags: c, string

I have a question about null char. i have a buffer `char buffer_2[245]`

```
memset(buffer_2, 0, 245);

strcpy(buffer_2, "Test");

strcat(buffer_2, "\0");
```

Do i need the third line? because isn't \0 autuomatically appended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i need the third line? because isn't \0 autuomatically appended.

You don't need the third line. `strcpy` appends the `'\0'`.

From `man strcpy`:

> The `strcpy()` function  copies  the  string  pointed to by src,
>   **including** the terminating null byte (`'\0'`), to the buffer pointed to by dest.  The strings may not overlap, and the destination string
>   dest must be large enough to receive the copy.  Beware of buffer
>   overruns!  (See BUGS.)

Also note that: Type of `"Test"` is `const char [5]` with values `'T'`, `'e'`, `'s'`, `'t'` and `'\0'`.

Comment: Thanku :) . one more thing is it a good practice to use `memset(buffer_2, 0, 245);` before copying to make sure there is no garbage value in the buffer ?

Comment: Though it is not mandaroty, but if `buffer_2` is `malloc`ed or received from client, I prefer to do a `memset` with `0` to avoid security issues. (It may contain some sensitive information)

Comment: @user2140086: You don't need the first line either.